# Как вывести 1 слово из переменной? Например

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, случайные-числа

Dir = r"C:\Users\user\desktop\error" #в папке например 4 файла как получить #одно название файла cofig.txt

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

Dir = r"C:\Users\user\desktop\error"
print(os.listdir(Dir)) # выводит список файлов в папке
```